# Beginner in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Can i learn Flex with out learning ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 3):

Learning Flex means learning both ActionSript 3 and Mxml languages, so in essence, you cannot learn Flex without learning ActionScript.

But if what you're really asking is whether you can learn Flex without prior ActionScript knowledge, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try some introductory tutorials to help understand the framework?  If you're familiar with other scripting languages then Actionscript shouldn't be too daunting.

Here are some decent tutorials to get started:
http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=705
http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Part+I.+Creating+a+Simple+RIA

I'd also recommend downloading "Tour de Flex" as a companion when getting started with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

flex is gud, as i am flex developer, you can start learning flex, but you hav to learn actionscript too, b'coz at the end of day, i found myself working and coding in actionscript,

so flex eases the things, that wre much time taking in Actionscript,

like

Here you don't need to add the child hbox in the vbox, that's been done automatically, and do note that flex code is compiled in to AS code first, then that is converted to bytecode,before given to flash player to execute....so u r most welcome to the flex world , but do note AS is also imoprtant, and it's very intertesting,:-)

tc

Ankur

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.  To do anything remotely useful you'll need to be able to write some actionscript.  You can easily do some layout, but mxml is really best for just creating views.  If you want to just create a 'hello world' program, then you can certainly do that with flex.  However, when you want to build something substantive you'll need actionscript.  Also note that the mxml tags are all written in actionscript, so if you want to understand them under the hood, you'll also need to know actionscript.